# Collapsible force-layout using darge-d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to render a directed graph in d3, and provide it collapsible force layout functionality like we see in this example : https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130

However, my graph would require bigger nodes with text on it, and my JSON-data is also formatted differently. Here's a working fiddle of my webpage just so you get an idea of what I want my graph to look like(I've also provided the Json-Data I get as input in the javascript section of the fiddle; it is a big graph so you'd have to scroll a bit to see the actual rendering) : https://jsfiddle.net/ashareah/zg42Lvx6/

`g.setNode` and `g.setEdge` functions are darge-specific and I run a loop to set them in my webapp using flask. I'm using darge-d3 https://github.com/dagrejs/dagre-d3 to do the rendering mainly because I haven't found how to get this working with d3 directly with the format of data I have.

I'm unable to figure out how to make my graph collapsible as we see in the first example. I'm also open to not using darge-d3 anymore because it's depreciated, if my graph is rendered perfectly and has the collapsible force layout functionality with d3 directly. How do I make my graph collapsible?